# Component variance estimate after taking the difference of normal variables

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation, variance

I have multiple observations  $z_i = x_i - y_i$ where $x_i\sim N(0,\alpha^2)$ and $y_i\sim N(0,\beta^2)$, where $\alpha^2$ is assumed known. Under these circumstances, what is a standard method of estimating $\hat{\beta^2}$?

Would it be $\hat{\beta^2} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i z_i^2 - \alpha^2$?

Are there other methods that have better properties (ie., unbiased, min variance etc.)?

Thanks!